# Changing the address book drop down from drop down list to radio buttons

Tags: shipping, onepage-checkout

We need to select option for radio button shipping and billing address on checkout page. How to change this?

Answer (score 2):

Step1: Copy the following file to local folder.

> app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php

Open this file and goto line :135

Remove the following lines

```
 $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
->setName($type.'_address_id')
                ->setId($type.'-address-select')
                ->setClass('address-select')
            ->setExtraParams('onchange="'.$type.'.newAddress(!this.value)"')
            ->setValue($addressId)
            ->setOptions($options);

        $select->addOption('', Mage::helper('checkout')->__('New Address'));
```

And Add the below line of code

```
$select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_radio')->setOptions($options)
            ->setName($type.'_address_id')
             ->setClass('address-select input-rdo')
             ->setExtraParams('onclick="'.$type.'.newAddress(!this.value)"')
             ->setValue($addressId);
```

Step2: Create a new file in the following folder

> app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Html/Radio.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Core
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2015 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */


/**
 * HTML select element block
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Core
 * @author     Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Core_Block_Html_Radio extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{

    protected $_options = array();

    /**
     * Get options of the element
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOptions()
    {
        return $this->_options;
    }

    /**
     * Set options for the HTML select
     *
     * @param array $options
     * @return Mage_Core_Block_Html_Select
     */
    public function setOptions($options)
    {
        $this->_options = $options;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add an option to HTML select
     *
     * @param string $value  HTML value
     * @param string $label  HTML label
     * @param array  $params HTML attributes
     * @return Mage_Core_Block_Html_Select
     */
    public function addOption($value, $label, $params=array())
    {
        $this->_options[] = array('value' => $value, 'label' => $label, 'params' => $params);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set element's HTML ID
     *
     * @param string $id ID
     * @return Mage_Core_Block_Html_Select
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->setData('id', $id);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set element's CSS class
     *
     * @param string $class Class
     * @return Mage_Core_Block_Html_Select
     */
    public function setClass($class)
    {
        $this->setData('class', $class);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set element's HTML title
     *
     * @param string $title Title
     * @return Mage_Core_Block_Html_Select
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->setData('title', $title);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * HTML ID of the element
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getData('id');
    }

    /**
     * CSS class of the element
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getClass()
    {
        return $this->getData('class');
    }

    /**
     * Returns HTML title of the element
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->getData('title');
    }

    /**
     * Render HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if (!$this->_beforeToHtml()) {
            return '';
        }
        foreach ($this->getOptions() as $key => $option) { 
            $select='';
        if($this->getValue() == $option['value']){
            $select ='Checked="checked"';
        }
            $html .="<div class='address_radio'><input type='radio' name='".$this->getName()."'  value='".$option['value']."' class='".$this->getClass()."'  " . $this->getExtraParams() . " ".$select."/><p>".$option['label']."</p></div>";
        }

        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * Alias for toHtml()
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHtml()
    {
        return $this->toHtml();
    }



}
```